# How to make React.ReactNode to indexable types?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
export interface Foo1 {
    bar1: React.ReactNode
}

class Foo2 extends React.Component<Foo1>{
    bar2 = () => {
        const { bar1 } = this.props;
        return bar1['this is a string']; 
    }
}
```

problems:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'React.ReactNode'.
>     No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'React.ReactNode'.

Comment: Why would ReactNode have a `this is a string` property? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Quick workaround `(bar1 as any)['string']`

Comment: @ritaj migrate others' react project from js to ts, so can not change the type of `bar1`!

Comment: Well than bar1 is NOT `React.ReactNode`

Comment: @keikai thank you, I figured it out !!!

Comment: `return (bar1 as any)['...string'];` right?